# Opencv cvSaveImage

Tags: image, opencv

I am trying to save an image using opencv cvSaveImage function. The problem is that I am performing a DCT on the image and then changing the coefficients that are obtained after performing the DCT, after that I am performing an inverse DCT to get back the pixel values. But this time I get the pixel values in Decimals(e.g. 254.34576). So when I save this using cvSaveImage function it discards all the values after decimals(e.g. saving 254.34576 as 254) and saves the image. Due to this my result gets affected. Please Help

Answer (score 0):

"The function cvSaveImage saves the image to the specified file. The image format is chosen depending on the filename extension, see cvLoadImage. Only 8-bit single-channel or 3-channel (with 'BGR' channel order) images can be saved using this function. If the format, depth or channel order is different, use cvCvtScale and cvCvtColor to convert it before saving, or use universal cvSave to save the image to XML or YAML format."

I'd suggest investigating the cvSave function.

HOWEVER, a much easier way is to just write your own save/load functions, this would be very easy:

```
f = fopen("image.dat","wb");
fprintf(f,"%d%d",width,height);
for (y=0 to height)
  for (x=0 to width)
   fprintf(f,"%f",pixelAt(x,y));
```

And a corresponding mirror function for reading.

P.S. Early morning and I can't remember for the life of me if fprintf works with binary files. But you get the idea. You could use fwrite() instead.